# Make Python http.server use correct content-type header for webp images

Tags: python, image, webserver, httpserver, webp

Trying to run a very simple local python webserver to serve a directory with some images in different formats like png, jpg and webp.

```
python3 -m http.server -d /path/webdir 8090
```

Unfortunately, webp images are served with the wrong header: `Content-type: application/octet-stream` instead of `Content-type: image/webp`

How can I fix this? (still using a oneliner to start the python webserver)

Yes I know `php` is doing it fine:

```
 php -t /path/webdir -S  localhost:8090
```

Comment: I think you might need more than a simple one-liner server for that... Probably a simple script... Although I might be mistaken.

Comment: you may have to write script with all server for this because it may not have information about `webp`. You may check [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/http/server.py) to see how it rcognize `Content-type` and how to change it.

Comment: base on source code it uses module [mimetypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mimetypes.html) to recognize type - `import mimetypes ;
 mimetypes.guess_type('name.webp')`. This module uses some files in system to recognize type - see `print( mimetypes.knownfiles )` - and maybe if you edit one of these files then it will recognize `webp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base on [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/http/server.py#L862) it uses module [mimetypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mimetypes.html) to guess type

```
import mimetypes  

print( mimetypes.guess_type('name.webp') )
```

Result

```
(None, None)
```

This module uses some files in system to guess type

```
print( mimetypes.knownfiles )
```

Result on Linux Mint 20 (based on Ubuntu 20.04)

```
[
 '/etc/mime.types', 
 '/etc/httpd/mime.types', 
 '/etc/httpd/conf/mime.types', 
 '/etc/apache/mime.types', 
 '/etc/apache2/mime.types', 
 '/usr/local/etc/httpd/conf/mime.types', 
 '/usr/local/lib/netscape/mime.types', 
 '/usr/local/etc/httpd/conf/mime.types', 
 '/usr/local/etc/mime.types'
]
```

If I add line in one of these files - ie. `/etc/mime.types`

```
image/webp                  webp
```

Then `mimetypes.guess_type('name.webp')` gives me

```
('image/webp', None)
```

and I think it should resolve proble with your server.

---

**EDIT:**

I tested `python3 -m http.server` before and after adding line in `/etc/mime.types` and it resolved problem on my Linux.

Comment: Great answer. `webp` and `avif` both missing in default Ubuntu 21.04 /etc/mime.types