# how can I force specific mime types for python's http.server?

Tags: python, http.server

I have a bunch of files without extensions, so http.server is serving them all as `application/octet-stream` and this is causing problems...

Rather than giving them extensions, I would like a way to define a dictionary that would be filename -> mimetype.  And then have GET requests to http.server look up the filename in that dictionary object, and set the `Content-type` header to its value.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make Python http.server use correct content-type header for webp images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67936829/make-python-http-server-use-correct-content-type-header-for-webp-images)

Comment: @Hermann12, no.  That is talking about using extensions to detect mimetypes.  I am looking for a way to set a content type based on a filename without an extension... 'file1' => 'text/html', 'file2' => 'application/json', 'file3' =>  'svg+xml', etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [extensions_map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.extensions_map) attribute of `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler`.
When adding a mapping from the empty string to your preferred type, it will serve files without extension as that.

```py
from http.server import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
from socketserver import TCPServer


def run():
    Handler = SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
    Handler.extensions_map = {'': 'text/plain'}
    with TCPServer(('', 8000), Handler) as httpd:
        httpd.serve_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Here's the output of `curl -I localhost:8000/myfile` (with a corresponding file put in the appropriate place).

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: SimpleHTTP/0.6 Python/3.11.7
Date: Tue, 16 Jan 2024 23:35:28 GMT
Content-type: text/plain
Content-Length: 26
Last-Modified: Tue, 16 Jan 2024 23:33:49 GMT
```

If you want to serve different types and really map from individual file names to the types, it's somewhat more involved.

You have to subclass and overwrite the behaviour of `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.guess_type`. Start reading [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b201a6a1f107ca3ff4201cb4dc3cd677db6cb52d/Lib/http/server.py#L880).

Should probably be something like this:

```py
def guess_type(self, path):
    from pathlib import Path
    path_name = Path(path).name
    return self.extensions_map.get(path_name, 'application/octet-stream')
```

This is a sledgehammer job, and I suggest you don't use this example as is and do some sensible error handling instead. You get the idea.